# What happens to my Youtube Channel if I cancel my G-Suite Subscription

Tags: email, youtube, google-workspace

I currently have a G-Suite Account with a personalised Email address.
I am looking to create a youtube channel that I wish to remain online for as long as youtube is alive.

However, I am aware that the G-Suite will come to an end at some point in the future.

So my question is,
Will my Youtube Channel also be closed and gone from that moment on?

Is it better for me to create a free generic Gmail account for the sake of Youtube as it will be subscription free and the videos will remain online forever?

Ideally, I would like to have the youtube channel under my personalised email address as thats my brand, but not if it will be deleted in the future.

Any advice is helpful

Comment: This sounds like a question that should be asked of somebody at Google. Unless an employee is on here, how would the rest of us know what the plan is for G-Suite's end of life?

Comment: I will start a chat thread with Google now. if the OP stays open, if I get an answer, I can post it for future ref